# How can I add "id" attribute to menu link on Joomla3?

Tags: joomla3.0

I need to add **"id"** attribute to my menu links generated in Joomla. Actually they are displayed like

```
<li>
<a href="/site/index.php">INICIO</a>
</li>
```

AND i need:

```
<li>
<a id="SOME-ID" href="/site/index.php">INICIO</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Joomla! default menu module, either you edit the menu module file located in: 
`/modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default_url.php` or you can use jQuery to add the id's according with your preferences and needs. The first approach would be preferable.